# Using awk command to display lines backwards

Tags: awk

Fairly new to the awk command and still playing with it, I am trying to display multiple lines of a file, lets say lines 3-5, and display it backwards. So with the given file:

```
Hello World
How are you
I love computer science,
I am using awk,
And it is hard.
```

And it should output:

```
science, computer love I
awk, using am I
hard.  is it And
```

Any step in the correct direction will be beneficial!!

Comment: What have you actually tried? `Any step in the correct direction will be beneficial!!` is not a valid question.

Comment: I pasted "I am trying to display multiple lines of a file, lets say lines 3-5, and display it backwards" into google. The first hit was this post, the second was [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336149/print-all-words-on-lines-of-a-file-in-reverse-order)

Comment: Hints, you will want awk's `NR` variable to filter out the lines, and loop over the fields using the `NF` variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following `awk` command to reach your goal:

**input:**

```
$ cat text 
Hello World
How are you
I love computer science,
I am using awk,
And it is hard.
```

**output:**

```
$ awk 'NR<3{print}NR>=3{for(i=0; i<NF; i++){printf "%s ",$(NF-i);} printf "\n";}' text                                                            
Hello World
How are you
science, computer love I 
awk, using am I 
hard. is it And
```

**Explanations:**

- `NR<3{print}` will print first 2 lines in the correct order
- `NR>=3{for(i=0; i<NF; i++){printf $(NF-i)" ";} printf "\n";}'` from the 3rd line you have a loop on all the field identified by `NF` and you print them one after another from the last one to the first one (`$NF` is the last one `$1` is the first one) and you separate each field with a space. Last but not least after the loop you print and EOL char.

Now, if you do not need to print the first 2 lines use:

```
$ awk 'NR>=3{for(i=0; i<NF; i++){printf "%s ",$(NF-i);} printf "\n";}' text                                                            
science, computer love I 
awk, using am I 
hard. is it And
```

For files with more lines for which you want to print only a range (3-5) use:

```
$ awk 'NR>=3 && NR<=5{for(i=0; i<NF; i++){printf "%s ",$(NF-i);} printf "\n";}' text
```

Comment: I believe OP need not to print 1st 2 lines, you could add that solution too in your post(along with current nice solution).

Comment: Edited ;-) Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: Thank you a lot for your feedback, I have edited the post and have replaced the `printf` with the proper syntax: `printf "%s", $(NF-i)`

Answer (score 2):

Following `awk` may help you in same, where I am using `start` and `end` variables to get only those lines which are needed to be printed by OP.

```
awk -v start=3 -v end=5 'FNR>=start && FNR<=end{for(;NF>0;NF--){printf("%s%s",$NF,NF==1?RS:FS)}}'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
science, computer love I
awk, using am I
hard. is it And
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation to solution too now.

```
awk -v start=3 -v end=5 '            ##Mentioning variables named start and end where start is denoting the starting line and end is denoting end line which we want to print.
FNR>=start && FNR<=end{              ##Checking condition here if variable FNR(awk out of the box variable) value is greater than or equal to variable start AND FNR value is less than or equal to end variable. If condition is TRUE then do following:
  for(;NF>0;NF--){                   ##Initiating a for loop which starts from value of NF(Number of fields, which is out of the box variable of awk) and it runs till NF is 0.
    printf("%s%s",$NF,NF==1?RS:FS)}  ##Printing value of NF(value of field) and other string will be either space of new line(by checking when field is first then print new line as print space).
}
' Input_file                         ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Wow nice answer! I like the range that can be dynamically passed to `awk` and your printing loop! Very clean

Comment: Decrementing NF is undefined behavior per POSIX so in some awks it'll remove the last field, in other awks it will leave the whole record as-is, and other awks could do anything else.

Comment: @EdMorton, let me try to fix it now and get back to you/.

Comment: Also, FS and RS are input separators, when outputting you should use OFS and ORS. If you end up with the same answer as I posted https://stackoverflow.com/a/48698548/1745001 I'll just delete mine.

Comment: Do you have to define an end with the -v option? Trying with just awk -v start=2 '{print $(NF-3)}' to get all lines after the header, but it is still capturing the count for the header. Not huge, just didn't know if it was required. I have a situation where the line count may exceed the current number.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR>2 && NR<6 {
    for (i=NF; i>0; i--) {
        printf "%s%s", $i, (i>1?OFS:ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
science, computer love I
awk, using am I
hard. is it And
```